# how to config lfs.fetchinclude in gitlabci

Tags: gitlab-ci, git-lfs

I want to git lfs fetch only in some dir in the gitlab CI. but failed

the gitlab-runner was 11.8.0~beta.1077

i config like this:

```
variables:
  # Please edit to your GitLab project
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  GIT_CHECKOUT: "false"

script:
  - git config lfs.fetchinclude "xxx/xxx/, test/"
```

but ci erro:

```
root config contains unknown keys: script
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The first part is your syntax error - the `script` key must be part of a job, e.g. like this:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - git config ...
```

However, I think the CI runner will fetch LFS files automatically, and the `script` is only run after cloning.

So I think you have to [disable automatic fetching](https://github.com/CESM-GC/CTSM/commit/59520bfec4eda9254e74d3ad61ce8a74b2e5e832) before, & then this might work:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - git config lfs.fetchinclude "xxx/xxx/, test/"
    - git lfs pull
```